# Proper way to insert into unordered map via function

Tags: c++

Say I have something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> *map;
```

as a field. I want to write a function like this:

```
void myFunc(std::string& s, std::string& s2){
    map->insert(std::make_pair(s, s2));
}
```

I cannot for the life of me get something along these lines to compile. Happy to post more code. But I've changed my map type from strings to ints and this works no problem. Thanks!

Comment: What compiler errors are you getting?  [Edit] your question with these details.

Comment: a) Post a [mcve]. b) Why are you asking something that you don't have a problem with?

Comment: My apologies, these comments where hidden. I was hitting hash errors. Did a little more digging and the answer is i did not include <string> . Sad life. Been awhile since I've cpp'd :D

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you use a pointer to the map? I noticed some strange issues with that. Make sure the map is actually getting created. But the following works (no pointer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    explicit Test() { }

    inline void myFunc(const string& s, const string& s2) {
        map.insert(make_pair<string, string>(s.c_str(), s2.c_str()));
    }

    inline void Print() const {
        for (const auto& entry : map)
            cout << entry.first << ", " << entry.second << endl;
    }

private:
    unordered_map<string, string> map;
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Test> test = make_unique<Test>();
    test->myFunc("Key", "Value");
    test->Print();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: c_str, doesn't sound like that should be needed